# git stash, jenkins pipeline, No git jobs using repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to setup triggering a jenkins multibranch pipeline from Atlassian Stash using the stash webhook to jenkins plugin. My project config has Build Periodically set to @daily, Periodically if not otherwise set to 1 day and I have indexed my branches however when I click on the 'Trigger Jenkins' button on the stash webhook config I get the following error

```
Error: Jenkins response: No git jobs using repository
```

I have previously read that this could be because polling is disabled on the project however there is no setting to enable it in the top level. I have tried enabling it in the master branch Jenkinsfile however it did not show up as checked when I 'View Configuration' for the master job. I can also see in the Jenkins logs:

```
no trigger, or post-commit hooks disabled, on my-repo » master
```

I can't find any other way to get this working?

Comment: When you're on the jenkins page for your specific branch in your multibranch pipeline, scroll all the way to the bottom and click the REST API link. If you scroll all the way to the bottom, you'll see a link there that if you goto, should schedule a build.

Answer (score 4):

The hint from Jenkins log you see is correct

```
no trigger, or post-commit hooks disabled, on my-repo » master
```

The post-commit hook on Jenkins side is disabled by default after job is created without explicitly turning it on. To enable it you should update `Build Triggers` configuration of the job that you want to be triggered (`my-repo » master` in your case) by selecting the following two triggers:

1. `[✓]` *Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket*
2. `[✓]` *Poll SCM* (**leave the *Schedule* text box empty**)

[image]

If you use Jenkins pipeline script instead of Jenkins UI then your `Jenkinsfile` should contain proper [`triggers`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) directive (corresponding to the above screen):

```
triggers {
  bitbucketPush()
  pollSCM('') // empty cron expression string
}
```

The important thing is leaving *Schedule* field text box empty. Otherwise, if you enter cron expression there then your build will be triggered twice. Once on commit-hook notification and the second one when cron expression trigger gets fired. It's explained by the label placed under the *Schedule* field:

> No schedules so will only run due to SCM changes if triggered by a post-commit hook

Comment: Jenkinsfile solution worked for me, Azure DevOps + WebHook + Jenkins